# Failing: Replace a single value with a new value for an individual DataFrame column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to replace some IDs in a column.

I am reading an excel file using `pd.read_excel` and storing it in a data frame:

```
df_A2C = pd.read_excel(file_loc1, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])
```

This can be reproduced with

```
df_A2C = pd.DataFrame({'FROM_ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 'TO_ID': [7, 26, 71, 83, 98],
 'DURATION_H': [0.528555555555556,
  0.512511111111111,
  0.432452777777778,
  0.599486111111111,
  0.590516666666667],
 'DIST_KM': [38.4398, 37.38515, 32.57571, 39.26188, 35.53107]})
```

After this, I am checking to see the values which I want to replace using this code:
`df_A2C.loc[(df_A2C['FROM_ID'] == 9)]`

**This gives an output:**

```
FROM_ID TO_ID   DURATION_H  DIST_KM FROM_ID
    9   7        1.183683   89.26777    9
    9   26       1.167639   88.21312    9
    9   71       1.087581   83.40369    9
    9   83       1.254614   90.08985    9
    9   98       1.245642   86.35904    9
```

Now, I am trying to replace `FROM_ID` values `9` with `8`.

I have tried the following codes.

`df_A2C['FROM_ID'] = df_A2C['FROM_ID'].replace('9','8')`

Also,

`df_A2C.loc[ df_A2C["FROM_ID"] == "9", "FROM_ID"] = "8"`

To test the results, I am doing `df_A2C.loc[(df_A2C['FROM_ID'] == 8)]`

**output:**

```
FROM_ID TO_ID   DURATION_H  DIST_KM FROM_ID
```

None of these are working.

I want to replace `FROM_ID values` `9` with `8`. I do not want to create another column, just want to replace existing column values.

**Am I making any mistakes here?**

Comment: do you have two columns with the same name? Please provide a minimal example how to test your code. Of course we don't have your xlsx

Comment: You maybe haven't done a mistake and the provided answer is probably not a good solution… That said, your example is weird, do you really have twice a `FROM_ID` column? In which case the chosen answer should fail. Please provide the output of `df_A2C.head().to_dict('list')` for reproducibility.

Comment: @RuggeroTurra I have already provided a data sample where I am having `FROM_ID´values as 9. These are data samples in my .xlsx file. I am trying to update the `FROM_ID` values.

Comment: @mozway  I do not have twice a `FROM_ID` column. Why did you say this? I have shared the ouput of `df_A2C.head().to_dict('list')`. Please check the updated question.

Comment: @LearningLogic I asked because this is what the output below "***This gives an output:***" shows. Anyway, using `df_A2C.loc[df_A2C['FROM_ID'].eq(9), 'FROM_ID'] = 8` should work fine. The issue was just the use of `"9"` in place of `9`. In any case, **do not** use `apply`, this is a **bad way** for this operation (uses a loop instead of vectorial computation)

Comment: @mozway Ah, very interesting. You can submit this as an answer with a reason. This might help others too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
df_A2C['FROM_ID'] = df_A2C['FROM_ID'].apply(lambda x: 8 if x==9 else x)
```

that is if your values are `int`

if your values are strings use this

```
df_A2C['FROM_ID'] = df_A2C['FROM_ID'].apply(lambda x: '8' if x=='9' else x)
```

Comment: Thank you. I was making mistake with the data type. My values are in `FROM_ID         int64`.

Comment: How can we use this code for changing multiple values e.g., if I want to change value 9 with 8 and value 20 with 18?

Comment: You can do it like this `df_A2C['FROM_ID'] = df_A2C['FROM_ID'].apply(lambda x: 8 if x==9 else 18 if x==20 else x)`

Answer (score 0):

Your solution based on `replace` works, I guess the problem is somewhere else (e.g. you have two columns labelled `FROM_ID`)

Let use the input example:

```
df_A2C = pd.DataFrame({'FROM_ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 'TO_ID': [7, 26, 71, 83, 98],
 'DURATION_H': [0.528555555555556,
  0.512511111111111,
  0.432452777777778,
  0.599486111111111,
  0.590516666666667],
 'DIST_KM': [38.4398, 37.38515, 32.57571, 39.26188, 35.53107]})
```

unfortunately there is no record with `FROM_ID` equal to 8, but all of them are equal to 1. So let assume you want to change 1 to 100.

```
df_A2C['FROM_ID'] = df_A2C['FROM_ID'].replace(1, 100)
```

then `df_A2C` is represented as

```
   FROM_ID  TO_ID  DURATION_H   DIST_KM
0      100      7    0.528556  38.43980
1      100     26    0.512511  37.38515
2      100     71    0.432453  32.57571
3      100     83    0.599486  39.26188
4      100     98    0.590517  35.53107
```

as expected. And you can also call `df_A2C.loc[(df_A2C['FROM_ID'] == 100)]` which returns the same result.